# The Data doesn't appear in the Database when inserted from php&code

Tags: php, mysql, database, comments, textarea

My code

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
$name=$_POST['name'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];

if($submit){
    if($name&&$comment) {
        $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')"); 
    }
    else {
        echo" please fill out the fields";
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            The comment box
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="mainpage.php" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2">Comment:</td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><textarea name="comment"></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="comment"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's very simple code, when I open the file I get these errors:

but they disappear after I add something in the textarea, but the inserted data doesn't go to database.

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\mainpage.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: comment in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\mainpage.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\mainpage.php on line 7
```

Please help I tried everything.

Comment: a) That code, as is, is vulnerable to SQL injection b) are you actually opening a connection in `connect.php` or just including the necessary classes/functions?

Comment: Also: What text are you currently typing into the input & textarea respectively to test the code?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<form action="mainpage.php" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="mainpage.php" method="post">
```

Possible (case-insensitive) values are `get` (the default) and `post`.

Instead of

```
 $submit=$_POST['submit'];

 if($submit){
```

, try to use `if (!empty($_POST))`

Before trying to access the variables that are posted through form, you have to check whether it is set or not using `isset()`. Because, at first time when you are accessing the page without submitting the form, it will throw error as the values are not posted.

Change the code to:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
if(!empty($_POST))
{
if(isset($_POST['name']))
   $name=$_POST['name'];
if(isset($_POST['comment']))
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
            $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')"); 

}
else {
        echo" please fill out the fields";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got the same errors. noting changed.

Comment: I tried to add this if (!empty($_POST)) the submit error disappear, but the rest still exist and noting shows in database

Comment: Updated my answer..I think there is some error in your sql..Try to echo the sql and execute it to find the errors.

Comment: Yeah there's was an small error and with your idea I got rid of the submit error thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `$var = $_POST['sth']`. Use this:

```
$sth = null;
if(isset($_POST['sth'])) {
    $sth = $_POST['sth'];
}
```

Or, a shorter way:

```
$sth = isset($_POST['sth']) ? $_POST['sth'] : null;
```

You can also use `''` or `false` instead of `null`

Replace this:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];
```

with this:

```
$name    = issset($_POST['name'])   ? addslashes($_POST['name'])    : false;
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? addslashes($_POST['comment']) : false;
$submit  = isset($_POST['submit'])  ? addslashes($_POST['submit'])  : false;
```

To check if there is a mysql error, replace this line:

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')");
```

with this:

```
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: All the errors have disappeared  I used this code as well

Comment: if (!empty($_POST))   and the one u suggested    $comment=null; if(isset($_POST['comment'])) {
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
}

Comment: But the Data doesn't appear in the Database.

Comment: I updated my answer. If the result is the same, add `if(!$insert) die(mysql_error()) else echo 'The data has been successfully insertted';` after the query

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 require('connect.php');
 if(isset($_POST)){    //use condition for post
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $comment=$_POST['comment'];
 $submit=$_POST['submit'];

 if($submit){

     if($name&&$comment){

     $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')"); 
     }
        else{

           echo" please fill out the fields";

      }


 }

 }


 ?>



 <html>

 <head>
 <title>
 The comment box
 </title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form action="mainpage.php" method="POST">
 <table>
 <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan="2">Comment:</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2"><textarea name="comment"></textarea></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="comment"/></td></tr>

 </table>
 </form>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your code as, Added `isset()` .

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $comment= $_POST['comment'];
        if(!empty($name) && !empty($comment)){
            $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comment` (`name`,`comment`) VALUES ('$name','$comment')") or die(mysql_error());
        }else{ 
            echo" please fill out the fields";
        }

    }
```

**Note:** Use mysqli_* or PDO functions instead of using mysql_* functions(deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

you should check if you have a form posted or not
use `if($_POST)` right after `<?PHP` and `}` before `?>`